# In C - warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat]

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a program which can do multiple different tasks, such as converting watts to dBm/dBW etc. and vice versa.

I have got the seperate programs working correctly on their own but when i attempted to combine them with a 'select which convertor to run' section i get compiler faults and the program fails as detailed below.

Here is the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int x=0,y=0,conv,a;
float dB1,dB2[15],W2[15],divide;
char ans,unit[3],ex;
double logans,W1;

int main()
{
    system ("color F0");
    system ("mode 75,50");
    do
    {
        if(y>0)
        {
            printf("\n\tIncorrect entry detected, please try again.");
            printf("\n\n\n\tPlease ");
            system("pause");
            y=0;
        }
        system("cls");

        printf("\n\tAvailable Convertors:\n\n\t1 = mW, W or kW to dBm, dBW and dBk respectively.\t");
        printf("\n\n\t2 = dBm, dBW or dBk to mW, W and kW respectively.");
        printf("\n\n\tPlease choose which convertor you would like to use: \t");
        scanf("%d",&conv);
        printf("\n\tYou entered: %d \n"),conv;
```

Here is the error i recieve:

[Error during operation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5tm.jpg)

And here are the compiler error messages i receive:

[Compiler error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x9Nn.png)

Comment: `printf("\n\tYou entered: %d \n"),conv;` Why is `conv` outside the function?

Comment: Somehow I suspect all the compiler errors are caused by parameters being outside the actual function.

Comment: Yes, thankyou, it did turn out to be that. Cheers for your help!

Comment: Interesting that you are displaying the image of a run time error in your program and yet the code does not compile!!

Comment: The program  doesn't fail to compile, it has compiler issues and then the program fails when run. I should have written compiler warnings instead of errors. Sorry if i unintentionally mislead you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here

```
printf("\n\tYou entered: %d \n"),conv;
```

replace with

```
printf("\n\tYou entered: %d \n",conv);
```

so that you actually **do** pass your `conv` variable to `printf()`

Comment: Cheers for the answer, i knew it would be me doing something simple incorrectly! haha.